# convert js output to objective C

Tags: javascript, objective-c, xcode

I am doing work on iphone app in which I have also used js as well as css files along with objective C to get better output. But at one point I stuck out. I am using the following js code which is showing the alert. I have attached the image also which is representing the alert by clicking on OK button.

```
**NSString *someHtmlContent1 = @"<script src='jquery.min.js'>
</script>
<script src='jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<script src='jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js'></script>
<script>
function result(qn) {
    var u = document.getElementById('sortable'+qn);
    var LIs = u.getElementsByTagName('li');
    var list = [];
    for( var i = 0; i < LIs.length; ++i ){
       var LI = LIs[i];list.push(LI.innerHTML);
    }
    res = list;
    var i=0;
    var str = '';
    for (i in res) {
        str = str+' '+res[i];
    }
    alert(str);
    return str;
}
</script>";**
```

[image]

I want to get the content**(.......)** in NSString which is showing on alert. Anyone know that how to convert js variables to objective C? Please do help me.

Thanks to all.

Comment: Serialize desired data using Json and then deserialize it.

Comment: use json or xml to pass values between both

Answer (score 0):

The only trick to make a link between JS and objective-C is the following one :

In your JS, call a link like  window.location = "something://smth/smthelse"

And in the Objective-C, in your web view delegate method (webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: ), you can handle this call and do something with it.